# Delete all pending scheduled cron jobs

Tags: wordpress, plugins, cron, scheduled-tasks

I need help with deleting scheduled action. Right now there are 21000+ Pending actions and I want to remove all of them. I'm seeing these pending tasks by using "Advance Cron Manager" WP plugin. I can clear cron job in WP_OPTION table but these job are not stored there. I asked the developer, since it's a free plugin so they only said "Use wp_unschedule_event function to clear them."

I've tried clearing cron jobs from wp-options table but those pending actions are not clearing.

Need help running wp_unschedule_event to clear all of those pending tasks
Thanks

Comment: Did you read the [manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unschedule_event)? Where are you stuck. You need to include your code and explain how it fails to do what you intend.

Comment: Otherwise if you have access to the server it's easy to find out where crontab files currently in use are depending on OS / distribution, then you just need to truncate those files and the jobs will not run. Obviously, you need to disable the source so they don't get scheduled in the firs place if you don't need them to run.

Comment: There is no coding I tried because I'm not a coder and don't know how and where to use this function. Could you help me with a code that can clear those jobs?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this hook to unschedule all previously scheduled cron jobs.

   ```
   <?php wp_clear_scheduled_hook( $hook, $args ); ?>
   ```
2. Try

   In SQL: `Update wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name ='cron'`

   In wordpress: `update_option('cron','');`

Comment: I've already tried clearing jobs by that SQL query. I doesn't clear those. Developer specially mentioned to use wp_unscheduled_event to clear those.

Comment: Here you can see my conversation. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/bulk-selection-of-scheduled-actions/

Answer (score -2):

why don't you disable **wp-cron.php** file? Simply paste this code in your **wp-config.php** file and no scheduled task works after you disable the cron file.

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

[How to Disable the wp-cron.php File for Your WordPress Site Using cPanel](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-disable-the-wp-cron-php-file-for-your-wordpress-site-using-cpanel/)

Comment: He wanted to clean the scheduled cronjob list, not deactivating the run of the queue.